# Jquery click is not trigger file input click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery click event not trigger only input type file. Why?

```
<input type="file" id="file">

$(function(){    
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#file").click();
        console.log("clicked");
    },2000);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aafwm4nt/

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `console.log("clicked");` in on file click function like following

```
$("#file").click(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("clicked");
    },2000);
});
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aafwm4nt/2/)**

Comment: Well I thought that OP wants to trigger file dialog pragmatically.

Comment: Thank for reply. But I want to open the form is opened after 2 seconds automatically

Comment: @user3080012 You will not be able to do it due to security reasons. At least not crossbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your framework to jQuery. The jsfiddle you linked has the framework set to pure javascript.

I set it to this:

[image]

and your code worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sadikhasan's Answer will work from second click onwards..You Might want to change it to:

```
$(function () {
    $("#file").click(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("clicked");
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

But to trigger something on click of file input is a bad idea I would recommend using `change` eventListener:

```
  $(function () {
        $("#file").change(function () {
                console.log("clicked");
        });
    });
```